# Beamer boxing a formula after a pause

Tags: beamer, pause, only

I am doing a presentation with Beamer and I need help with the use of \only<.> and \boxed{}.

I would like to get the following effect:

1. a=b+c
2. a=b+c

   c=d
3. a=b+d

   c=d
4. a=b+\boxed{d}

   c=d

I used the following code but I don't like the effect because when it put the box around d it moves also "c=d". Could someone help me to find a different code?

```
\begin{align*}
a=b+\only<1-2>c
\only<3>{d}
\only<4>{\boxed{d}}
\end{align*}
\pause
c=d
```

So I would like to get the "d boxed" after that "a=b+d" appears without moving "c=d".

Could someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

**First:** you don't use `align` properly. You have to write "c=d" inside the environement`align`, and "glue" the two equations with an `&`.

**Second:** you have to precisely align "d" correspondig to the differences between the width of `d` and `\boxed{d}`.

There are two solutions (assuming that the frame is center-aligned); both of the should work, but shomehow the second is better.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

% For both solutions
\usepackage{calc}

% Just for the second solution
\newlength{\firslength}
\settowidth{\firslength}{\boxed{d}}
\newlength{\secondlength}
\settowidth{\secondlength}{d}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

% First solution
\begin{align*}
a=&b+\only<1-2>{\hspace*{(\widthof{\boxed{d}}-\widthof{d})/2}c\hspace*{(\widthof{\boxed{d}}-\widthof{d})/2}}%
\only<3>{\hspace*{(\widthof{\boxed{d}}-\widthof{d})/2}d\hspace*{(\widthof{\boxed{d}}-\widthof{d})/2}}%
\only<4>{\boxed{d}}\\%
\uncover<2->{c=&d}%
\end{align*}

% Second solution
\begin{align*}
a=&b+\only<1-2>{\hspace*{\dimexpr(\firslength-\secondlength)/2}c\hspace{\dimexpr(\firslength-\secondlength)/2}}%
\only<3>{\hspace*{\dimexpr(\firslength-\secondlength)/2}d\hspace{\dimexpr(\firslength-\secondlength)/2}}%
\only<4>{\boxed{d}}\\%
\uncover<2->{c=&d}%
\end{align*}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that `\boxed{d}` has a different width than `d`. Tom Solid's solution, unfortunately, looks awkward with the extra spacing inserted.

I'm not sure where you're getting `\boxed` from (I guess it gets loaded indirectly by beamer) but I've found it defined in multiple packages as:

```
\newcommand{\boxed}[1]{\fbox{\m@th$\displaystyle#1$}}
```

(or its equivalent). Digging into the definitions of `\fbox` there is extra space of `\fboxsep` surrounding the box contents inside the box plus the width of the lines which is `\fboxrule`. We can use this to make a new command, `\bxed` (or whatever you prefer to call it) which will remove the space that has been added so that the box spills into the existing white space around `d` when its printed.

```
\newcommand{\bxed}[1]{\mbox{\kern-\fboxsep\kern-fboxrule\boxed{#1}\kern-\fboxsep\kern-fboxrule}}
```

This should give the desired result.

Also, the `&` in the `align` environment should come *before* the `=` and not after it. You'll notice in Tom's example that the spacing between *a* and = is larger than the spacing between = and *b*. Moving the ampersand fixes that issue.